# Query to edit data grid view using textboxes

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

Here's my current code:

```
private void editButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection.Open();

        try
        {

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();

            command.Connection = connection;

            string query = string.Format(
@"update Customer 
  set Title='{0}',
      [Name]='{1}',
      Member='{2}',
      Email='{3}',
      [Phone No]='{4}',
      [Facility]='{5}',
      [Unit Size]='{6}',
      [Start Date]='{7}',
      [Rent Duration]='{8}',
      [End Date]='{9}',
      [Storage Item]='{10}',
      [Air Condition]='{11}',
      [Total Monthly Cost]='{12}',
      [Total Rental Cost]='{13}' 
  {14}", 
 titleComboBox2.Text,
 nameTextBox2.Text,
 memberComboBox2.Text,
 emailTextBox2.Text,
 phoneNoTextBox2.Text,
 facilityComboBox2.Text,
 unitSizeComboBox2.Text,
 start_DTP2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
 rentDurationTextBox2.Text,
 end_DTP2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
 storageItemComboBox2.Text,
 airConComboBox2.Text,
 totalMonthlyCostTextBox2.Text,
 totalRentalCostTextBox2.Text, 
 "where TransactionNo=" + idTextBox.Text + "");

            command.CommandText = query;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data edited");


        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
```

Here's how I want my program to work:

1) User enters the transaction number of the data which he/she wants to edit into idTextBox

2) User can then choose which value he/she wants to edit. For example, if he/she wants to edit the name of the customer, he/she should key in the new name into nameTextBox2 and leave the rest blank

3) User clicks the edit button and data should be updated according. The old name should be replaced by the new one entered by the user. The rest of the data should remain the same. E.g. Email of customer should remain the same, not blanked

However my program requires me to key in values into every single textboxes and comboboxes for it to work. Why is it that?

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate you query based on the value of textboxex. Update only if value not empty

```
StringBuilder query = New StringBuilder();
//Name
if (this.nameTextBox2.Text.Length > 0)
{
    query.AppendLine(", [Name]=@Name");
    command.Parameters.Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = this.nameTextBox2.Text;
}
//Email
if (this.emailTextBox2.Text.Length > 0)
{
    query.AppendLine(", Email=@Email");
    command.Parameters.Add("@Email", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = this.emailTextBox2.Text;
}
// ... 
// And other control in same way
// Then check if something updated
if(query.Length == 0)
    Return;
// Remove first "," character if updates exists
query.Remove(0,1);
query.Insert("UPDATE Customer SET ");
query.AppendLine("WHERE TransactionNo=@TranNo");
OleDbParameter tranno = New OleDbParameter("@TranNo", OleDbType.Integer);
tranno.Value = Int32.Parse(this.idTextBox.Text);
command.Parameters.Add(tranno);
// Run query
command.CommandText = query.ToString();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Remember to use `Parameterized query` as @Soner was mentioned in the comments

Another approach can be loading current data to textboxes after transaction number was input.
Then your query will update changed values and copy values which wasn't changed after editing